# docker build --memory on windows 10

Tags: docker

I am trying to build a container on my Windows 10 machine to run unit tests. I use `docker build --memory 4g --tag test .`. I am using image - `microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk-alpine`. My tests run fine on my Windows 10 Client using `dotnet test Tests`. When running in the container, they run fine till memory execeds 1GB, then they fail with - out of memory.

How do I increase the memory for my container during build on Windows 10 client?

Docker works fine for me locally. I run Linux containers and Windows containers locally. The windows containers are just hosting simple APIs so they likely never excede 1GB of RAM. I don't run Linux & Windows simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I increased the RAM of the MobyLinuxVM running in Hyper-Vfrom 2GB to 8GB, while and increased the amount of RAM available per container from 2GB to 6GB and that solved my problem.

Comment: Could you provide the steps to do this?